# Refering SPGRIDVIEW.ROWS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, spgridview

I am using 'spgridview' in one of my sharepoint applications as follows.

```
<sharepoint:spgridview id="sample grid" visible="false" runat="server"
                autogeneratecolumns="false" width="100%" allowpaging="true"/>                    
            </sharepoint:spgridview>
```

I need to use the number of rows in the spgrid in a javascript function.So how can I refer the grid in javascript and how can I get the number of rows in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Put a label total no of rows  and get as splist.items.count . Now refere this label and its text in java script or jquery